# Subplot ( Side to side ) in python Dash

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, graph-visualization

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='g1', figure={'data': [{'y': [1, 2, 3]}]}), className="six columns",style={"width": 500, "margin": 0}),

        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='g2', figure={'data': [{'y': [1, 2, 3]}]}), className="six columns",style={"width": 500, "margin": 0}),

    ], className="row")
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The above code supposed to be side to side like this:

[It supposed to produce and I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEHrE.png)

But unfortunately,[The above code produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3P4T.png) I am getting like this:

Comment: Probably your screen is not wide enough, so it adds a linebreak… try reduce the width maybe

Answer (score 2):

**Got the solution from one of my colleagues**

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div(
          dcc.Graph(id='g1', 
                    figure={'data': [{'y': [1, 2, 3]}]}), 
                    className="six columns",
                    style={"width":500, "margin": 0, 'display': 'inline-block'}
                ),
        html.Div(
          dcc.Graph(id='g2', 
                    figure={'data': [{'y': [1, 2, 3]}]}), 
                    className="six columns",
                    style={"width":500, "margin": 0, 'display': 'inline-block'}
                ),
    ], className="row")
])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```