# Django + plotly-dash: cannot render graphs side to side

Tags: python, html, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I have followed this [Subplot ( Side to side ) in python Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170645/subplot-side-to-side-in-python-dash) and [How to add multiple graphs to Dash app on a single browser page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459424/how-to-add-multiple-graphs-to-dash-app-on-a-single-browser-page), to find a way to get graphs rendering side to side in my template.

I cannot get it to work, the size of the graphs are adjusting well, but they keep rendering one below the other. I am confused about what is going wrong, and as I am just picking up dash, I am struggling to identify the root cause of the issue.

UPDATE: As adivced in the comments, i have tried including graph1 and graph2 inside as children of one div tag and display, however it still does not let get two graphs next to each other.

Here is what my file looks like:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
import dash_table
import os 
#external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
external_stylesheets =  'home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/staticfiles/css/style.css'
app = DjangoDash('tryout', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df_bar = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df_bar, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    
    
    # All elements from the top of the page
html.Div(children=[
        
        
        html.Div(children=[
            html.H1('Hello Dash'),

            html.Div(''' Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''),

                dcc.Graph(id='graph1',figure=fig, style={"width":500, "margin": 10,'display': 'flex'}),  
            
                html.H3('Hello Dash'),
                dcc.Graph(id='graph2',figure=fig, style={"width":500, "margin": 10,'display': 'flex'}),   
], 
),
        html.Div(children=[
             html.H1('Hello Dash', style={"width":500, "margin": 0,'display': 'flex'}),

             html.Div('''Dash: A web application framework for Python.''', style={"width":500, "margin": 0,'display': 'inline-block'}),
                dcc.Graph(id='graph2',figure=fig, style={"width":500, "margin": 0,'display': 'flex'}),                  
                ]),
    
        html.H1('Hello Dash'),

        html.Div('''Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''),
        dcc.Graph(id='graph3',figure=fig, style={"width":500, "margin": 0,'display': 'flex'}
        ),  

    ], className='row'),

    html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

        html.Div(children='''
            Dash: A web application framework for Python.
        '''),
        
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',

    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_bar.columns],
    data=df_bar.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action='native',
    filter_action='native',
    export_format='csv',


    style_cell={'textAlign': 'center', 'font-size' : '16px','width': '10px',
        'overflow': 'hidden'
},


    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(248, 248, 248)'
        }
    ],
    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
        'font-size' : '20px'
    }

)
    ], className='six columns')
    
])
```

still no luck, I can't find a way to get it to work

Comment: I take it you have a CSS file as well somewhere. Not sure what styles you're setting, but I would recommend using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to do this.

Comment: i have a css file indeed. I am a bit confused on how to make flexbox work in this python file to achieve the display I try to get

Comment: You'll need one `div` that contains both the graphs as its `children`, and it should be given the `display: flex` property either in your CSS file or by setting the `style` prop in Python.

Comment: i thought I understand your advice @coralvanda but it still not workout out

Comment: hey @Murcielago were you able to eventually figure out how to render them side by side using django-plotly-dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this locally and it worked. I eliminated your stylesheets so I could show the CSS here using the `style` prop.

```py
    html.Div(children=[

        html.Div(
            style=dict(display='flex', height=500),
            children=[
                html.H1('Hello Dash'),

                html.Div(''' Dash: A web application framework for Python.'''),

                dcc.Graph(id='graph1', figure=fig,
                          style={"width": 500, "margin": 10, 'display': 'flex'}),

                html.H3('Hello Dash'),
                dcc.Graph(id='graph2', figure=fig,
                          style={"width": 500, "margin": 10, 'display': 'flex'}),
            ],
        ),
    ], className='row'),
```